# Stretch floating child to 100% height of parent?

Tags: html, css

Is this possible using CSS only?  I can't find a definitive answer anywhere!

It's for a left and right nav bar I'd like to stretch to 100% height; i.e. the end of the page.  There are three floated columns contained within a floated container that stretches 100% height, I just can't get the childs to stretch...

http://www.dev.inside-guides.co.uk/brentwood/pages/links.html

Thanks in advance for any replies.

Comment: I think [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) are your solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done, if you set its parent div container position to relative as follows

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
```

and then set the div you want to be 100% and position absolute as follows

```
#inner {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

this is how I've done it, hopefully I haven't missed anything :)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before.
Try adding:

```
html{
 height:100%;
}
```

Make sure the parent div has a set height and the div itself is also height:100%;

If you have any trouble let me know :)